# Is catch an error here? should i use parameter for catch()?

Tags: c#, exception, parameters, try-catch, visibility

Following code is working properly for first two selection of country(textbox10). But not working from 3rd selection. while selecting "united states" a single textbox(textbox4) should appear and for other country selection two other textboxes(posttxt and phonetxt) should appear. It is working fine for first two selection but not working from third selection. what should i do? should i use parameters for catch?

```
private void textBox10_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        ComboBoxItem country_list = null;
        country_list = (ComboBoxItem)textBox10.SelectedItem;

        if (country_list.Content.ToString() != "United States")
        {
            textcombobox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            cmbState.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

            textBox4.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            posttxt.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            phonetxt.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            textcombobox.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            cmbState.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

            textBox4.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            posttxt.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            phonetxt.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Which exception it's throwing?

Answer (score 4):

actually putting some form of error handling code in your catch block would be a good start. just catching all exceptions is very bad practise, doing nothing in there just leaves you guessing what went wrong. I would suggest removing the try/catch if your only purpose is to stop an error showing, and just figure out the root cause of the error

Comment: My purpose is to make it run for every selection of textbox10. Selecting "United states" will display textbox4 but selecting any other country will display posttxt and phonetxt. It is working when im selecting "United states" 1st time. then also working when im changing it to any other country. But after that when im changing it again to "United states" it is not displaying the proper textbox. It is remaining unchanged for further selection. so where is the prob?

Comment: so, you've added the try/catch because you're getting some kind of error. rather than find the root cause you are simply hiding it. i suspect you may fix the problem you're having by finding and fixing the root cause.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to look at that exception in the debugger, you can have Visual Studio catch all thrown exceptions by clicking the "Debug -> Exceptions..." menu and making sure that "Thrown" column for Common Language Runtime Exceptions is checked.

[image: Visual Studio Exception Dialog]